# Linux List Graphic Processes

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'm new to Linux and need to query, via bash if process's gui is visible.
Is there any bash command to perform this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may, or may not, be able to use `xwininfo`, especially the "Window State" property in the Window manager hints, but it may have drawbacks when using multiple workspaces/desktops, so make sure you test that extensively in different environments. It also needs to be installed manually on some distributions.

```
$ xwininfo -name "MyWindowName" -wm
```

The most universal solution I can think of would be to query the current UI state from the application itself, using some IPC mechanism.

And you should better move this question over to [SE Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).